# How can I get an IObservable<T> in Rx from a "non-standard" event?

Tags: .net, vb.net, system.reactive

Here's what I mean. Suppose I'm working with an API that exposes events, but these events do not follow the standard `EventHandler` or `EventHandler<TEventArgs>` signature. One event might look like this, for instance:

```
Public Event Update(ByVal sender As BaseSubscription, ByVal e As BaseEvent)
```

Now, typically, if I want to get an `IObservable<TEventArgs>` from an event, I can just do this:

```
Dim updates = Observable.FromEvent(Of UpdateEventArgs)( _
    target:=updateSource, _
    eventName:="Update" _
)
```

But this doesn't work, because the `Update` event is not an `EventHandler<UpdateEventArgs>` -- in fact, there *is* no `UpdateEventArgs` -- it's basically just its own thing.

Obviously, I could define my *own* class deriving from `EventArgs` (i.e., `UpdateEventArgs`), write another class to wrap the object providing the `Update` event, give the wrapper class its *own* `Update` event that *is* an `EventHandler<UpdateEventArgs>`, and get an `IObservable<UpdateEventArgs>` from *that*. But that's an annoying amount of work.

Is there some way to create an `IObservable<[something]>` from a "non-standard" event like this, or am I out of luck?

---

**UPDATE**: From Jon Skeet's answer, I'm nudged in the direction of the following overload of `Observable.FromEvent`:

```
Function FromEvent(Of TDelegate, TEventArgs As EventArgs)( _
    conversion As Func(Of EventHandler(Of TEventArgs), TDelegate), _
    addHandler As Action(Of TDelegate), _
    removeHandler As Action(Of TDelegate) _
) As IObservable(Of IEvent(Of TEventArgs))
```

I have to admit, though, I'm having trouble wrapping my head around that `Func(Of EventHandler(Of TEventArgs), TDelegate)` part. It seems backwards to me (?). Obviously, there's just something I'm missing...

Anyway, in case it helps, I *think* this is what the equivalent C# code would look like (I'll be perfectly honest: I'm not sure about this. Even though I generally prefer C# myself, this code is the work of one of my colleagues, who writes primarily in VB.NET; and VB.NET permits multiple syntaxes for declaring events):

```
// notice: not an EventHandler<TEventArgs>
public delegate void UpdateEventHandler(BaseSubscription sender, BaseEvent e);

// not 100% sure why he did it this way
public event UpdateEventHandler Update;
```

The tricky part here is that it seems that **some** kind of class deriving from `EventArgs` is necessary, no matter what. In the API I'm working with, there is no such class. So, bare minimum, I'll have to write one. But that should be fairly trivial (basically one property: `BaseEvent`).

In the end, I'm assuming the code required for this overload would look something like this in C#:

```
var updates = Observable.FromEvent<UpdateEventHandler, UpdateEventArgs>(
    // conversion (Func<EventHandler<UpdateEventArgs>, UpdateEventHandler>)
    handler => (sender, e) => handler(sender, new UpdateEventArgs(e)),
    // addHandler (Action<UpdateEventHandler>)
    handler => updateSource.Update += handler,
    // removeHandler (Action<UpdateEventHandler>)
    handler => updateSource.Update -= handler
);
```

First of all: do I even have this straight? Second of all: am I correct in saying that using VB 9, there's really no way to accomplish the above without writing my own methods?

It almost feels to me like I'm approaching this problem from the entirely wrong angle to begin with. But I'm really not sure.

Comment: Your C# example was correct, the way to do it in VB is the same, but the syntax is a bit messier.  See the example I posted below for future reference.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you could just add your own implementation for the custom event signature?

```
public interface ICustomEvent<TSource, TArgs>
{
    public TSource Source { get; }
    public TArgs EventArgs { get; }
}

public interface CustomEvent<TSource, TArgs> : ICustomEvent<TSource, TArgs>
{
    public TSource Source { get; set; }
    public TArgs EventArgs { get; set; }
}

public static class ObservableEx
{
    public static IObservable<ICustomEvent<TSource, TArgs>> FromCustomEvent(
        Action<Action<TSource, TArgs>> addHandler, 
        Action<Action<TSource, TArgs>> removeHandler)
    {
        return Observable.CreateWithDisposable(observer =>
            {
                Action<TSource, TArgs> eventHandler = (s,a) => 
                    observer.OnNext(new CustomEvent<TSource,TArgs>(s,a));

                addHandler(eventHandler);

                return Disposable.Create(() => removeHandler(eventHandler));
            });
    }
}
```

Then you can use it as:

```
var observable = ObservableEx.FromCustomEvent<BaseSubscription,BaseEvent>(
    h => updateSource.Update += h,
    h => updateSource.Update -= h
);
```

Comment: This looks quite promising. I'm going to check this out.

Answer (score 1):

You *may* be able to use this signature:

```
Public Shared Function FromEvent(Of TDelegate, TEventArgs As EventArgs) ( _
    conversion As Func(Of EventHandler(Of TEventArgs), TDelegate), _
    addHandler As Action(Of TDelegate), _
    removeHandler As Action(Of TDelegate) _
) As IObservable(Of IEvent(Of TEventArgs))
```

Here, `TDelegate` would be the delegate type of the event (which I can't tell immediately from your declaration - C# event declarations don't look quite like that, and I'm afraid I don't know enough VB to decypher it, but I'm sure there's a delegate type there somewhere). `TEventArgs` would be a type for the event argument (`BaseEvent` should do it here, I think). You'd need to provide a converter from an `EventHandler(Of BaseEvent)` to your delegate type - this would probably just be a lambda expression to call the given event handler with the arguments passed into it. The add and remove actions would be the normal event subscription code - but expressed as delegates.

Unfortunately my VB isn't good enough to express all of this neatly - or indeed to know how much is easily available in VB 9 or 10. I know how it would all look in C#... if you could give me a short but complete example in C# which just left me to fill in the subscription bit, I could certainly do that...

Comment: This definitely seems like a promising option. I've updated my question with what I *believe* is the C# equivalent of the VB.NET code I originally posted. If you get a chance to read my update: does my C# version of the hypothetical code I'd need to write look correct to you? I know you said you're not very familiar with VB, so I guess I'm on my own when it comes to working out that part...

Answer (score 1):

You can also just do this the lazy way, if updateSource never goes away:

```
var observable = new Subject<BaseEvent>();
updateSource.Update += (o,e) => observable.OnNext(e);
```

Jon's plan is probably a better one though, but Subjects can help you out.

Answer (score 1):

For future reference, this is an example of using the conversion overload of FromEvent, using the FileSystemEventHandler as an example:

```
    Dim createWatcher As New FileSystemWatcher With {.Path = "C:\Temp", .EnableRaisingEvents = True}
    Dim foo = Observable.FromEvent(Of FileSystemEventHandler, FileSystemEventArgs)(
        Function(ev) New FileSystemEventHandler(Sub(o, e) ev(o, e)),
        Sub(ev) AddHandler createWatcher.Created, ev,
        Sub(ev) RemoveHandler createWatcher.Created, ev)

    Dim changedEv = Observable.FromEvent(Of FileSystemEventHandler, FileSystemEventArgs)(
        Function(ev) New FileSystemEventHandler(Sub(o, e) ev(o, e)),
        Sub(ev) AddHandler createWatcher.Changed, ev,
        Sub(ev) RemoveHandler createWatcher.Changed, ev)

    foo.Subscribe(Sub(e) Console.WriteLine("File {0} created.", e.EventArgs.Name))
    changedEv.Subscribe(Sub(e) Console.WriteLine("File {0} changed.", e.EventArgs.Name))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var updates = Observable.FromEvent<UpdateEventHandler, UpdateEventArgs>(
     // conversion (Func<EventHandler<UpdateEventArgs>, UpdateEventHandler>)
     handler => (BaseSubscription sender, BaseEvent e) => handler.Invoke(sender, new UpdateEventArgs(e)),
     // addHandler (Action<UpdateEventHandler>)
     handler => updateSource.Update += handler,
     // removeHandler (Action<UpdateEventHandler>)
     handler => updateSource.Update -= handler 
);
```

Make sure UpdateEventArgs ctor accepts a BaseEvent argument.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar nightmare because I'm working with an interop API that uses non standard .net events. I'm a beginner on a lot of things including Generics, Funcs, Actions, Observables and Rx so I believe that my experience on how to understand such things will be of some value.

We can get your head around `Func(Of EventHandler(Of TEventArgs), TDelegate) conversion` by understanding where it is used.

But first we must understand the generics signature of the `FromEvent` method.

Below is function signature of the FromEvent extension method in vb:

```
Function FromEvent(Of TDelegate, TEventArgs As EventArgs)( _
    conversion As Func(Of EventHandler(Of TEventArgs), TDelegate), _
    addHandler As Action(Of TDelegate), _
    removeHandler As Action(Of TDelegate) _
) As IObservable(Of IEvent(Of TEventArgs))
```

But I do not really use vb so I will have to resort to the c# signature:

```
IObservable<TEventArgs> FromEvent<TDelegate, TEventArgs>(
    Func<Action<TEventArgs>, TDelegate> conversion, 
    Action<TDelegate> addHandler, 
    Action<TDelegate> removeHandler);
```

Let's analyze the c# signature line by line.

Note: There will be times that I will include Data types in lambda expressions as to differentiate standard .net events from non-standard events.

**First part:**

```
IObservable<TEventArgs> FromEvent<TDelegate, TEventArgs>(
```

This says that function FromEvent accepts a `TDelegate` and `TEventArgs As EventArgs` as INPUT. Notice that the the OUTPUT `IObservable` will also have the type of `TEventArgs` So you are right when you said that you need a class that that will wrap the data of `TDelegate`. I don't know what version I'm using but it lets me use any class even if it doesn't inherit from `EventArgs`. In case vb doesn't let you, it's trivial work anyway since it's just appending `:EventArgs` to the class(Inherits from vb?). Let's apply this to your problem:

Your c# assumptions:

```
// notice: not an EventHandler<TEventArgs> public delegate void
public delegate void UpdateEventHandler(BaseSubscription sender, BaseEvent e);

// class to wrap the data from the above delegate
public class UpdateEventArgs:EventArgs {...}
```

Applying to the first line becomes:

```
var updates = FromEvent<UpdateEventHandler, UpdateEventArgs>(
```

**Second Part:**

Next, we have three inputs `conversion`, `addhandler`, and `removehandler`:

```
Func<Action<TEventArgs>, TDelegate> conversion, 
Action<TDelegate> addHandler, 
Action<TDelegate> removeHandler);
```

We know that `addHandler` and `removeHandler` just adds and removes the delegate from an event. Let's do those two first.

```
// addHandler (Action<UpdateEventHandler>)
handler => updateSource.Update += handler,
// removeHandler (Action<UpdateEventHandler>)
handler => updateSource.Update -= handler
```

Now lets apply our type to the tricky part:

```
Func<Action<UpdateEventArgs>, UpdateEventHandler> conversion,
```

This function takes an `Action<UpdateEventArgs>` as input and a `UpdateEventHandler` delegate is the output. Let's assign it in a variable called `conversion`

```
Func<Action<UpdateEventArgs>, UpdateEventHandler> conversion 
    = (handlerOfUpdateEventArgs) =>
    {
        UpdateEventHandler handler = (BaseSubscription sender, BaseEvent e) => 
            handlerOfUpdateEventArgs(sender, new UpdateEventArgs(e));
        return handler;
    };
```

To better understand what this does, let's look at how we attach an event handler to a standard .net event:

```
someObject.SomeEvent += (object sender,EventArgs args) => { ... };
```

Now we look at your non standard .net event and `UpdateEventHandler`:

```
 public delegate void UpdateEventHandler(BaseSubscription sender, BaseEvent e);
 updateSource.Update += (BaseSubscription sender, BaseEvent e) => { ... };
```

If you look back at the signature of `conversion` function, it returns an `UpdateEventHandler` delegate. This would mean that we can use `conversion` to attach to the `Update` event. But before we can do that, the `conversion` function needs an `Action<UpdateEventArgs>` as input before it can be used. Let's do that now:

```
//EventHandler<EventArgs> similarity.
Action<UpdateEventArgs> actionUpdateEventArgs = (UpdateEventArgs e) =>
    {
        //This is were you put your code like in a standard.net event
        //This is also probably where the Observable.FromEvent() puts 
        //wiring necessary to make it into an IObservable<UpdateEventArgs>
    };
```

Now that we have all the parts that we need, we can use `conversion` similar to an event handler.

```
updateSource.Update += conversion(actionUpdateEventArgs);
```

Code within `actionUpdateEventArgs` will be called each time `Update` is raised.

Hopefully, that was enough explanation to understand the parameter `Func<Action<UpdateEventArgs>, UpdateEventHandler> conversion`.

Finally, this is how you'll use the `FromEvent()` method:

```
Func<Action<UpdateEventArgs>, UpdateEventHandler> conversion 
    = (handlerOfUpdateEventArgs) =>
    {
        UpdateEventHandler handler = (BaseSubscription sender, BaseEvent e) => 
            handlerOfUpdateEventArgs(sender, new UpdateEventArgs(e));
        return handler;
    };

var updates = Observable.FromEvent<UpdateEventHandler, UpdateEventArgs>(
    // conversion (Func<EventHandler<UpdateEventArgs>, UpdateEventHandler>)
    conversion,
    // addHandler (Action<UpdateEventHandler>)
    handler => updateSource.Update += handler,
    // removeHandler (Action<UpdateEventHandler>)
    handler => updateSource.Update -= handler
);
```

This is how I understood it form a newbies point of view so I hope it will be helpful.